# What do these two C warnings mean exactly?

Tags: c, warnings, function-pointers

have the following C code:

```
typedef void*(m3_func)(void);
#define NULL ((void*)0)

char* lolinfo()
{
    return "You got the additional info! :D";
}

m3_func** m3_funcs() {
    return (m3_func**) {
        (m3_func*)(&lolinfo), // warning #1
        NULL
    }; // warning #2
}
```

I'm getting these warnings:

- /home/lk/proj/m3/m3_lolauncher/lolauncher.c(0,0): Warning: **initialization from incompatible pointer type** (m3_lolauncher)
- /home/lk/proj/m3/m3_lolauncher/lolauncher.c(0,0): Warning: **excess elements in scalar initializer** (m3_lolauncher)

I dont understand the first one as i cast correctly?

I've never seen the second one...

Comment: That's a lot of lol's...

Comment: What these warnings are *really* trying to tell you is that you should probably read an introductory book on C before going any further

Comment: Then please let me L.O.L. at myself in ten minutes; "oh man was i dumb not understanding these simple errors" :) ?

Comment: I don't think that typedef does what you hope....

Comment: @awoodland Changing it to `typedef void(*m3_func)(void);` (and making the above code correct according to this change,), i get the same warnings. i guess not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems your sample code is not valid C.

if i understand your code, the `m3_funcs()` function should return a NULL terminated array of function pointers. you are actually trying to use an initializer (`{...}`) to declare an array and return it right away. but i don't think you can use an initializer outside of a variable declaration... also, note that this "variable" would exists only in the context of the `m3_funcs()` call, so the address that might eventually be returned would no more be valid after the function has returned.

the correct way to implement such a feature is to have a static global variable, and return its address:

```
static m3_func *m3_funcs_array[] = {(m3_func *)&lolinfo, NULL};

m3_func ** m3_funcs()
{
    return &m3_funcs_array;
}
```

Comment: You've got an error, m3_func in your first line should be m3_func*. Thanks for the answer, adopted it :)

Comment: oops, sorry, i will correct this right away. i may have made more mistakes, but hopefully you get the idea...

Answer (score 1):

A list initialization would be:

```
a = { b,c,d }
```

What you are doing here is using the new universal initialization (`x{y}`). Hence, you're trying to initialize a single `m3_func**` pointer with two `m3_func*` pointers. Ergo you have two warnings:

1. initialization from incompatible pointer type ( `m3_func**` != `m3_func*` )
2. excess elements in scalar initializer ( a pointer is a scalar, and you're trying to initialize it with two pointers -- ergo one excessive )